# node.js how to assemble file upload?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing an image upload in node.js, I have uploaded a file from the client:

```
    <form id="frmImgUpload" 
          enctype="multipart/form-data"
          action="/uploads/"
          method="POST">
      <input id="btnFile"
             style="float:right;"
             type="file"/>
      <input id="btnUpload"
             style="float:right;"
             type="button"
             value="Upload"/>
    </form>
```

The code to perform the upload:

```
    $("#btnUpload").click(function() {  
      $("#btnFile").attr("name", strCompanyKey);                    
      $("#frmImgUpload").submit();
    });
```

On the server I have displayed the data (just a small snippet):

```
    [ '------WebKitFormBoundaryI206ASCJdnqVyOo0\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="syberdyne"; filename="simonplatten.png"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n�PNG\r\n\u001a\n\u0000\u0000\u0000\rIHDR\u0000\u0000\u0000�\u0000\u0000\u0000l\b\u0006\u0000\u0000\u0000Ԃ\b�\u0000\u0000\u0000\tpHYs\u0000\u0000\u000b\u0013\u0000\u0000\u000b\u0013\u0001\u0000��\u0018\u0000\u0000\nOiCCPPhotoshop ICC profile\u0000\u0000xڝSgTS�\u0016=���BK���KoR\u0015\b RB��\u0014�',
    '*!\t\u0010J���\u0015Q�\u0011EE\u0004\u001bȠ�\u0003����\u0015Q,\f�\n�\u0007����������{�kּ������>������\u0007�\b\f�H3Q5�\f�B\u001e\u0011�������.@�\n$p\u0000\u0010\b�d!s�#\u0001\u0000�<<+"�\u0007�\u0000\u0001x�\u000b\b\u0000�M��0\u001c��\u000f�B�\\\u0001��\u0001�t�8K\b�\u0014\u0000@z�B�\u0000@F\u0001���',
```

What I would like to do is reassemble this data into the original file.  Are they're any API's or tutorials that will help me to achieve this?

I've split the content received from the client:

```
    var strBody = "";
    request.on("data", function(chunk) {
      strBody += chunk;
    });
    request.on("end", function() {
      console.dir(strBody.split("\r\n"));
    });
```

This results in:

```
    [ '------WebKitFormBoundarynBkMCKI8RBvIReTF',
      'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="syberdyne";filename="simonplatten.png"','Content-Type: image/png','','�PNG','\u001a\n\u0000\u0000\u0000\rIHDR\u0000\u0000\u0000�\u0000\u0000\u0000l\b\u0006\u0000\u0000\u0000Ԃ\b�\u0000\u0000\u0000\tpHYs\u0000\u0000\u000b\u0013\u0000\u0000\u000b\u0013\u0001\u0000��\u0018\u0000\u0000\nOiCCPPhotoshop ICC profile\u0000\u0000xڝSgTS�\u0016=���BK���KoR\u0015\b RB��\u0014�&*!\t\u0010J���\u0015Q�\u0011EE\u0004\u001bȠ�\u0003����\u0015Q,\f�\n�\u0007����������{�kּ������>������\u0007�\b\f�H3Q5�\f�B\u001e\u0011�������.@�001\u0000O��y���7\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000IEND�B`�',
      '------WebKitFormBoundarynBkMCKI8RBvIReTF--',
      '' ]
```

This is just a snippet of the data, it looks like the binary data is encoded somehow, is there a routine I can call to decode it?

I've installed 'formidable', what do I parse it?

Comment: https://coligo.io/building-ajax-file-uploader-with-node/

Comment: @Ouroborus, I've downloaded formidable, what do I parse it, I'm not using express.

Comment: Formidable does have [documentation](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable/blob/master/Readme.md). It appears that you pass in the request object and a callback function. The callback and some events are available to allow you do something with the form data. The `field` and `file` events are probably of interest to you.

Comment: @Ouroborus, thank you, I will investigate tonight.

Comment: @Ouroborus, if you create an answer I will tick it off, this works great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) is "a node.js module for parsing form data, especially file uploads."

According to its [documentation](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable/blob/master/Readme.md), you pass requests in and it allows you to access the form data conveinently via a callback function or through events.

Via optional callback:

```
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
  // ...
});
```

And via events:

```
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

form.on('error', function(err) {
  // ...
});

form.on('field', function(name, value) {
  // ...
});

form.on('file', function(name, file) {
  // ...
});

form.parse(req);
```

Comment: Thank you, works well, except the uploaded file name isn't how I have set, its something like 'upload_30f582d3347732dd2629b99e91a14b72'  looking into this now.

Comment: @SPlatten You may be able to access the client supplied file name as the `name` attribute of the file object, e.g.:`file.name`.

Comment: I have corrected the file name, but the file type is still wrong.

Comment: @SPlatten Mime-type should be under `file.type` and should be whatever the client decided it should be.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `multer` package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

Multer adds a body object and a file or files object to the request object. The body object contains the values of the text fields of the form, the file or files object contains the files uploaded via the form.

**Example**:

```
var express = require('express')
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

var app = express()

app.post('/profile', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.file is the `avatar` file 
  // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any 
})
```

Comment: It looks like you would use 'multter' for posting from the server to itself, how does this help decode the received data?

Comment: you will have saved file on your server - e.g. in `uploads` directory, and you could read it from there using fs.readFile

Comment: Thats not what I want, I want the clients to be able to select a file and upload it to the server, then the server saves it to the local file system.

Comment: this is exactly what multer package is doing - from the example above any file posted to `profile` endpoint will be saved on the server side in `/uploads` directory.

Comment: The code in the example is posting from the node application, not the client.  I will investigate, but so far I don't see an example of anything like what I am trying to do.

Comment: I'm not using express, so how do I direct the posted data to multer?

Comment: multer is the express middleware, if you want to use it as a standalone, the best approach would be to study source code, especially `_handleFile` function: https://github.com/expressjs/multer/blob/master/storage/disk.js#L28